# Always return NPE when using Map Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, parse-platform, geocoding, mapfragment

I'm using the below code to try and add a marker to a location after converting a string address into a LatLng. But the app always crashes with a NPE error. I tried debugging and it shows error at the lines shown by comments.I confirmed that none of the variables used there are null. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {
            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> address;
            LatLng p1 = null;
            try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
            if (address != null && address.size() > 0) {
                Address location = address.get(0);
                p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            } else {
                p1 = new LatLng(19.111258, 72.908313);
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return p1;
            }
            return p1;
        }

        public void prepareMap() {
            final LatLng REST = getLocationFromAddress(restAddress + ","
                    + restLocation);
            int zoomNiveau = 15;
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(REST).title(restName));//error points here
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(REST, zoomNiveau));
    }
```

Comment: If there were no null variable there wouldn't be an error. Please log `map`, `REST` and `restName` just before the error line. The output in your question would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things on that line that could cause a NPE - I would separate it out a bit so you can narrow down the problem.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(REST).title(restName));
```

Could be changed to...

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.position(REST);
options.title(restName);
map.addMarker(options);
```

The REST variable looks fine to me, so my bet would be on 'map' or 'restName'.

Note the following from the Android docs on MapFragment:

```
If a GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.
```